# 404 ErrorDocument to handle the request at posts Links

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I am working on a site called **windowsy.net** and got a problem of **404 ErrorDocument** to handle the request at posts pages.

Home page is opening fine but all other pages are getting that error.

Comment: What is your file structure? You probably don´t have access to the folder.

Comment: Incredibly tricky for someone to help given they can't see how the site is working/file structure/contents of your .htaccess. Posting more information will help.